# Two reading problem in GTM173 on Page 19

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

It is my first time reading this GTM$167$ and learning the Galois theory.

(1) I don't understand what's the meaning of 'inclusion reversing correspondence'. I guess it refers to the 1 and 3 in the Lemma 2.9. Is that right?

(2) In the second picture, 'a necessary condition from part $5$ is that $F$ is the fixed field of Gal($K/F$)'. Why is that?

[image: first picture]
[image: second picture]

Comment: The corollary states the existence of a correspondance between subgroups of the Galois group and intermediate field extensions. Both have a partial order by some inclusion. The “inclusion-reversing correspondance” means that if you have objects $A$, $B$ in one of the sets, such that $A \subset B$, then the corresponding object to $B$ is contained in that of $A$. So, indeed it refers to the part 1 and 3 of lemma 2.9 .

Comment: For (2): the corollary states the existence of a bijection “subgroups that are Galois groups” <-> “some intermediate field extensions”. What that part wants to do is to show that this is (under some conditions) a bijection “all subgroups of the Galois group” <-> “all intermediate field extensions”. In this case, it is necessary that $F$ is the fixed set of some subset of automorphism $S$. Then, by part 5, $F$ must be the fixed subfield of $Gal(K/F)$.