# How to use Cayley's theorem to prove the following?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, galois-theory

How to prove the underlined part in this example using the Cayley's Theorem? Thanks for help. I have no idea on it.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What text is this from?

Comment: GTM$173$, Field and Galois theory.

Comment: Ah, so the same text as [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558098/two-reading-problem-in-gtm173-on-page-19). Who is the author?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Patrick Morandi.

Comment: Thank you ( I found the book [here](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387947532)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlined part follows directly from **Cauchy's Theorem** (not Cayley's theorem, which is about embedding into a symmetric group):

[Proving Cauchy's theorem (group theory)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177795/proving-cauchys-theorem-group-theory)

For $p=5$ and $p\mid | G|$, Cauchy's Theorem gives an element of order $p=5$ in $G$.

Answer (score 2):

As @DietrichBurde noted in their answer and a comment below, it's really *Cauchy's theorem* that matters here. Every element must have an order dividing $5$, i.e. equal to $1$ or $5$. But they can't all be of order $1$.

Comment: Emmm,, I still do not understand... Is there any relation to the Cayley's theorem which says any finite group is isomorphic to a permutation group?

Comment: @ZWJ I suspect that the author confused "Cauchy" with "Cayley". Both sound French and start with Ca. We obtain the embedding into $S_5$ not by Cayley but rather because it is the Galois group of a quintic.